# How to binding a List<List<string>> To ListView in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm building a User Control with ListView of n columns, so I have a List of Lists:

C#:

```
public List<List<string>> ListItems { get; set; }

var itemList = new List<string>();
itemList.Add("1");
itemList.Add("John Doe");

ListItems.Add(itemList);

itemList = new List<string>();
itemList.Add("2");
itemList.Add("Jane Doe");

ListItems.Add(itemList);

itemList = new List<string>();
itemList.Add("3");
itemList.Add("Sammy Doe");

ListItems.Add(itemList);
```

XAML:

```
<ListView Name="lvwLista" Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="Single" ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems, ElementName=ucListaCompletarControl}">
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=.}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

But I don't Know how to binding the `List<List<string>>` to ListView.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody, my solution was a string with items in only row and add it to List:

C#:

```
public static List<string> ListItems { get; set; }

for(...)
{
 for(...)
 {
  var itemList = string.Empty;
  itemList += item.ToString() + "\t";
 }
 ListItems.Add(itemList);
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListView Name="lvwLista" Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="Single" 
        ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="False"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems, ElementName=ucListaCompletarControl}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="{Binding}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing `List<string>` in the ItemTemplate and so you can bind its properties as always.

```
<ListView Name="lvwLista"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems, ElementName=ucListaCompletarControl}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Item[0]}"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Item[1]}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Or

```
<ListView Name="lvwLista"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems, ElementName=ucListaCompletarControl}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I populating the lists with a loop and I don't know the columns number. How I can show in DataTemplate all columns?

Comment: If so, add ListView or other ItemsControl in DataTemplate.

Comment: Thanks, works but I need add a click event in the rows and this complicate this function, sorry hehe.

Answer (score 0):

Following link titled; "Binding a list of lists to a GridView which contains GridLists in WPF" maybe helpful for you.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9e04b734-ba83-47d5-a50e-d0544d28e69f/binding-a-list-of-lists-to-a-gridview-which-contains-gridlists-in-wpf?forum=wpf

Comment: Thanks but I don't know the columns number in Listview, can be 2, 5, etc.